# отправка картинки на сервер не из input[type='file']

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!)
Нужна подсказка, как мне отправить картинку из  на сервер?
Задача такова, я делаю скрин некой области монитора скриптом, формируется canvas, я его методом `canvas.toDataURL("image/png"))` добавляю в некий блок на странице где есть , но потом этот снимок мне нужно отправить на почту. Пытался засунуть его в input[type='file'], но ничего не выходит. Может есть какие способы отправить скрин на почту?

Comment: отправляй через `ajax`, с переменной `data: { 
     imgBase64: dataURL
  }` .... а на сервере это самый `base64` переводи в картинку и отправляй

Comment: var th = $(this);
    var file_data1 = screenfile.prop('files')[0];
    var form_data  = new FormData(th[0]);
    form_data.append('file', file_data1);

вот так вставляю файл, а как тогда картинку?)

Comment: ну например отдельным параметром `{ formData: form_data, imageDataURL: canvas.toDataURL()}`

Comment: form_data.append('img', temp);
///
$screen1 = $_POST['img'];
$screen1 = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $screen1);
$screen1 = str_replace(' ', '+', $screen1);
$result_screen = file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($screen1));
$mail->addAttachment($result_screen);
///
файл остаётся на сервере, причём в корневом каталоге и не прикрепляется к письму, в ём может быть проблема?

Comment: Задача решена =)